# Session variable becomes null in AJAX request (but is not in AuthorizeAttribute)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have controller

```
public sealed class DetailsController : SiteController
{
    [IsLoggedIn]
    public JsonResult GetDetais()
    {
        var guid = new Guid(this.UserId);
        // some code
    }
}
```

The action is called from partial class using:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "@Url.RouteUrl(..., new {action = "GetDetails", controller="Details"})",
dataType: "json"
```

}

UserId is stored in Session. It is the user Guid. If it is null the AuthorizeAttribute 'IsLoggedIn' redirects to SignIn page.

In Production we have multiple errors in new Guid(this.UserId) because UserId == null.
Have you any ideas how can it be? If it is passes AuthorizeAttribute (so it's not null there) it should be not null inside the action, isn't it?

Comment: You don't show the code around `this.UserId`? Where does it get set? If `GetDetails()` isn't setting it, something needs to. Otherwise it will be null, as you see.

Comment: How do you handle the AJAX request on server side? Is SessionHttpModule used in that request? Are you requesting Session access in your AJAX method? Session has to be accessed in a thread-safe manner, which usually means locking the entire Session syncobject, which means the same user can't do two requests at once, which is why Session is usually inacessible by default and you have to request it manually.

Comment: You are using this.UserId... It appears that UserId is defined in the SiteController class (or in a parent class even further up).  If so, it should be base.UserId.  As for the error, is your session timing out?  Keeping a user ID in the session is usually a bad idea because you can't guarantee that it will be there.  Use a cookie instead.